# .NET project Nunit tests are failing during mono build

Tags: c#, mono, nunit, travis-ci, nunit-3.0

I'm pretty new to CI (from a brand new set up point at least). I created a project in Rider, using the default version of NUnit that is provided if you select to 'Create new NUnit Project', and I am now trying to set up an automated build for it using travis-CI.

The target .NET framework version of my project and test projects (confirmed in Project properties in Rider) is 4.5.

The version of Nunit I am using is the default version provided with Rider, 3.5.

Here is my .travis.yml build file:

```
language: csharp
solution: .sln
install:
  - nuget restore FindWordsWithConcatenations.sln
  - nuget install NUnit.Runners -Version 3.5.0 -OutputDirectory testrunner
script:
  - xbuild  /p:Configuration=Debug ./FindWordsWithConcatenations.sln
  - mono ./testrunner/NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.5.0/tools/nunit-agent.exe ./TestFindWordsWithConcatenations/bin/Debug/TestFindWordsWithConcatenations.dll
```

I confirmed on my own machine by running the nuget command that the test runner path should be correct, when I run the nunit-agent (via agent, agent-x86, or agent-console) I get the following error (locally, and on the server):

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
   at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
   at NUnit.Agent.NUnitTestAgent.Main(String[] args)
```

I've also tried running with no configuration mode specified, and with configuration mode of Debug and Release specified.

Unfortunately, the normal tactic of googling/stack overflow hasn't helped, I've seen this error in a few questions, but the cause never seems related to what I'm experiencing.

[The last build of the pipeline is available to view here](https://travis-ci.org/dahui58/FindWordsWithConcatenations/builds/283985212), all the builds thus far have failed, previous builds can be seen [here](https://travis-ci.org/dahui58/FindWordsWithConcatenations/builds).

Thanks in advance, I would be very grateful if someone had any idea about the cause of this issue, or how I could tackle the test running in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Updated the script section of the travis config to:

```
script:
  - xbuild  /p:Configuration=Debug ./FindWordsWithConcatenations.sln
  - mono ./testrunner/NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.5.0/tools/nunit3-console.exe ./TestFindWordsWithConcatenations/bin/Debug/TestFindWordsWithConcatenations.dll
```

So it's now running the correct console application. Also had to modify the test paths a bit for it to run on the server.